# Daily reputation cap: points subtracted

Tags: discussion, support, daily-reputation-limit

Hi,
I reached for the first time the daily reputation cap. The day after I have seen my reputation level down to -150/-200 I don't remember.

Are points awarded to get d.r.c. subtracted when cap reached?

Comment: Your question really isn't clear. Please edit your question to ask more clearly, with examples.

Comment: You might have been the "victim" of a serial up-voter whose votes were removed by the vote fraud detection mechanism.

Comment: *detracted* or *subtracted*  ???

Comment: Thx Chris, I just invited a couple of colleagues to SO.com, they could be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with ChrisF -- I think you had some votes that were invalidated as statistically anomalous.

We have a process that runs every 24 hours and checks for voting anomalies, and removes any votes that are far outside statistical norms.